# Unable to run SQL Server stored procedure query in SSMS after adding credential parameter

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am new to using using stored procedure and Azure storage account. I am exploring the following guide at:
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-and-perform-a-sql-server-database-restore-from-azure-blob-storage/
and have created a credential in my database 'Security' > 'Credential' folder in SSMS.

Query that I ran in SSMS:

```
--using the url and the key
CREATE CREDENTIAL [Credential_BLOB]
WITH IDENTITY= 'https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/',
SECRET = '<storage account key -> which I enter my Access Key 1>';
```

Result:

[image]

After which I proceed to run the following stored procedure where I want to restore the backup from BLOB storage:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Database_Name FROM URL = 'https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/Container/SampleDatabase.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'Credential_BLOB',
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 41901, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> One or more of the options (credential) are not supported for this statement in SQL Database Managed Instance. Review the documentation for supported options.

However, from the guide which I input the link above, they were able to run the query:

[image]

I tried to google for the syntax of the RESTORE statement from the Microsoft Docs library and others who may have encountered similar issue but I did not find any effective result. I would appreciate your help if you have encountered something similar and would like to share your solution. Thank you!

Comment: error message clearly states that CREDENTIAL is not a valid option for RESTORE on a sql managed instance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @MitchWheat yes, but following the guide on https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-and-perform-a-sql-server-database-restore-from-azure-blob-storage/  they were able to run the query with that parameter

Comment: @DaleK yes, I understand. I am trying to explain my issue and what I have tried out

Comment: @RichardRodjues you can do that better and clearer without using images, instead add as formatted text as we will be able to read it easily on all devices.

Comment: @MitchWheat In this case, how can I restore the stored procedure using the credential parameter then?

Comment: @DaleK ok noted on that. I have changed the error message as formatted text instead of images

Comment: are you sure that article is using  a ' sql managed instance' and not just SQL Azure?

Comment: You should probably follow a more modern guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql

Answer (score 0):

From the error which you have shared, it is easy to interpret that you are using the SQL Database Managed Instance. But the link you have shared doesn't mention anywhere which SQL Server it is using. The approach mentioned in that link might not work in your case because of difference in SQL servers and statement compatibility.

Then, I tried the steps which are given in the Microsoft official document (link shared by [@Nick.McDermaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid) in the comment section). It is working fine without any issue.

Please follow the steps below to achieve the requirement (applicable for SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later, Azure SQL Managed Instance only).

Use the GUI in SQL Server Management Studio to create the credential by following the steps below.

1. Connect with your SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later or Azure SQL Managed Instance

[image]

2. Right-click your database name, hover over **Tasks** and then select **Back up** to launch the Back Up Database wizard.
3. Select **URL** from the **Back up to** destination drop-down, and then select **Add** to launch the Select Backup Destination dialog box.

[image]

4. Select **New container** on the **Select Backup Destination** dialog box to launch the Connect to a Microsoft Subscription window.

[image]

5. Sign in to the Azure portal by selecting **Sign In** and then proceed through the sign-in process. Select your subscription from the drop-drown.
   Select your storage account from the drop-down. Select the container you created already from the drop-down. Select **Create Credential** to generate your Shared Access Signature (SAS). **Save this value as you'll need it for the restore.**

[image]

I also tried to restore the database using the newly created credential and it is working fine.

To create the credential using T-SQL, please follow the steps provided in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-use-azure-blob-storage-service-with-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#1---create-stored-access-policy-and-shared-access-storage).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Is there anyway to use T-SQL as the solution instead of manually going through the UI as my current project will call the stored procedure upon button action?

Comment: Please refer to the link I mentioned in my comment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql it looks like you can use what you have, but you simply need to omit the `with credential` altogether

Comment: @Richard I updated my answer with the link to create the credential using T-SQL.